# C# checkbox status not swithing back to unchecked state

Tags: c#, checkbox

I am writing a C# code for the checkbox here. I want to get the checkbox unchecked if the messsagebox replies with "No". But it still in checked status. I have tried several ways but not working yet. I think my logic is correct but the output is not.
`chkComplete.Checked = false;` is not working.

```
    private void chkComplete_BeforeCheckStateChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs args)
{
    // ** Place Event Handling Code Here **
    if (!chkComplete.Checked) {

        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to complete this project?", 
                              "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        switch(dr)
        {
           case DialogResult.Yes:
                MessageBox.Show("Please make sure the project is saved!");
                epiShapeC1.Enabled = true;
                break;
           case DialogResult.No:
                MessageBox.Show("The project will stay incomplete!");
                chkComplete.Checked = false;
                epiShapeC1.Enabled = false;
                break;
        }
    } else {
         epiShapeC1.Enabled=false;
        }


}
```

Comment: Which checkbox are you talking about here? The only one I can readily see is `chkComplete`, but then the whole if-statement won't execute if this is already unchecked. As such it is a bit unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: `chkComplete.Checked = false;` is only exected if `chkComplete.Checked` is false, hence you won't see how it is becoming unchecked.

Comment: Note that you're in a *Cancel* event. If you want to circumvent what is going to happen to the checkbox, you should set the Cancel property on the `e` parameter. If you don't do that, the normal handling of the checkbox will occur.